# Python multiprocessing works in linux but not in windows

Tags: python, linux, windows, multiprocessing

I have a multiprocessing script which i tried both in linux and windows

In linux it works fine but in windows the script is running some random unknow results and script is not even ending

script

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
def get_urls1():
    res = [1,2,3,4,5]

    nprocs = 20 # nprocs is the number of processes to run
    ParsePool = Pool(nprocs)
    #ParsePool.map(btl_test,url)
    ParsedURLS = ParsePool.map(extractData,res)

def extractData(r):
    print r

get_urls1()
```

Linux output

```
1
3
2
5
4
```

But when i run the same script in windows it is not giving exact result as linux and script is not even ending(But if i remove multiprocessing the script works)

What should i fix to make multiprocessing work?

Comment: You should be calling `.close()`/`.terminate()` on the pool after `map`ing to ensure the workers will end when they complete their work, but falsetru's answer is the main issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [`multiprocessing` documentation - Programming guidelines - Windows](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#windows)

> Safe importing of main module
>
> Make sure that the main module can be safely imported by a new Python interpreter without causing unintended side effects (such a starting a new process).
>
> ...
>
> Instead one should protect the “entry point” of the program by using
>   `if __name__ == '__main__':` as follows:
>
> ...

So, guard get_urls1() call with `if __name__ == '__main__'`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_urls1()
```